# SQL how to replace multiple characters in a single field of the same table with single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to replace a particular character with another in my `Postgres` database using `SQL`. I am able to do that using two queries. I am not able to execute the queries together as it gives me an error. But when I execute them one after another, it works fine. The queries are as follows:

```
UPDATE simple_web_content
SET content_data = REPLACE(content_data, '“', '"') WHERE simple_web_content_type = 'B';

UPDATE simple_web_content
SET content_data = REPLACE(content_data, '’', '''') WHERE simple_web_content_type = 'B';
```

Is there any way I can combine them to a single query to execute them at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of error are you getting when you combine them?  Are you combining them like this?

```
UPDATE simple_web_content 
SET content_data = REPLACE(REPLACE(content_data, '’', ''''), '“', '"') 
WHERE simple_web_content_type = 'B';
```

Comment: how can I update the query if I have few more characters to replace

Comment: This helped me better,

Answer (score 1):

try `translate`?..

```
t=# select translate('’fyva’“oldj“','’“',e'\'"');
  translate
--------------
 'fyva'"oldj"
```

so I suppose for you it would be smth like:

```
UPDATE simple_web_content
SET content_data = translate(content_data, '“’', e'"\'') 
WHERE simple_web_content_type = 'B';
```

Comment: thanks for the update, but I am new to this. Can you help me with the query that I have posted